# Is Ubuntu to Wine a good Idea for digital artists/gamedevs?

Tags: ubuntu, wine

I am not very knowledgeable about Linux, but from what I have heard as far as wine goes, is that it can make your program faster than windows, slower than windows, and just the same.

The reason I want to get wine is so I can use Clip Studio Paint.
I am a digital artist (3d and 2d) and I use Blender and want to use Clip Studio Paint, I also do some programming and am getting into using Unity and Unreal engine, I am just wondering if using wine will make running and using any of these programs would make it work really slowly.
Any help would be very appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: Welcome to the site. The problem with your question is that, as you already stated, there is no general rule on how running a program under `wine` will affect its performance, so it is likely to attract rather opinion-based answers unless someone has tested exactly the programs you intend to use (which may of course be the case). It seems there is a trial version to Clip Studio Paint, so you may want to simply try installing `wine` and running the program to see if (and how fast) it works.

Answer (score 1):

The goal of `wine` is just to make application run on POSIX systems. It has nothing to do with speed and that is not a main concern, it doesn't even get its own field in the applications database. Information on performance goes into the comments.

Each application might run faster, slower, at the same speed or even not at all. It depends, among other things, on the compatibility layers that those applications use and how well `wine` implements them (if at all).

Users report the results of trying application with wine [here](https://appdb.winehq.org/index.php). You can check if the application you want is listed and how well it has worked for the reporters.

An alternative is a virtual machine or to search another application that natively supports your needs and workflow. In the end, it pays off, since an application that now works perfectly (platinum) `with` wine might not even start (garbage) after an upgrade.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I am honestly quite dumb when it comes to these technical things so I appreciate your input. :)